# Selecting everything from table with two innner joins and grouping by

Tags: sql-server

I'm coming here as a last resort of needed help.
Basically I have a table which contains links to that have fk to another table, then that another table needs to take out info based of its fk key to another table. Not sure if it has any meaning @_ @

SQL that doesn't work but been trying to make it for hours:

```
SELECT episode_number,film_episodes.episode_date, fk_film_id, episode_id FROM film_episodes
                                                    INNER JOIN films ON films.film_id = film_episodes.fk_film_id
                                                    INNER JOIN fiber_link_ep ON film.episode_id = film_link_ep.fk_episode_id
                                                    WHERE film_episodes.episode_id = film_link_ep.fk_episode_id
                                                        GROUP BY episode_number, episode_date, episode_id, fk_film_id
                                                        ORDER BY film_episodes.episode_date DESC
```

This one tho...works but gives me doubled elements instead of just one. So lets say that I have two elements with fk_id = 2 so it shows two elements instead of grouped by only 1 element.

```
SELECT * FROM film_episodes    INNER JOIN films ON films.film_id = film_episodes.fk_film_id
                               INNER JOIN fiber_link_ep ON film_episodes.episode_id = film_link_ep.fk_episode_id
                               WHERE film_episodes.episode_id = film_link_ep.fk_episode_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `select distinct` keywork or `group by` the **column** which you want to to get your unique results instead of double!!

PS : Unable to add a comment - hence adding an answer !